# PHP Nullable Types not working as expected

Tags: php, php-7

I wanted to know if the new feature of nullable types can be used to change the syntax in this working function from

```
function getCustomerId($id = null)
{
    return $id ?: 2;
}

echo getCustomerId();
```

to something like this which isn't working for me.  I get the error for too few arguments.

```
function getCustomerId(?int $id)
{
    return $id ?: 2;
}

echo getCustomerId();
```

so that basically if the argument is not provided it returns 2, but if the argument is provided it returns that argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yer kinda confusing the concept of *optional* arguments with the concept of *nullable* ones.

An *optional* arguments means you don't need to pass it cos it's optional.

A *nullable* argument means that whilst the argument needs to be of a certain type, that `null` is also valid (where it wouldn't be if it wasn't nullable). Nullability doesn't mean you don't need to pass anything; you still do. It can just be `null`.

If you want to have an integer argument which is optional and considered null if not passed, then combine yer two examples:

```
function getCustomerId(?int $id=null)
{
    return $id ?: 2;
}
```

Ref: [PHP > New Features > Nullable types](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.nullable-types)